# What difference between `$data["xxxx"]` AND `$xxxx`?

Tags: php, variables

What's the difference between `$data["xxxx"]` AND `$xxxx` ?

I have seen `$data["xxxx"]` in some page, then i want to know What is difference between `$data["xxxx"]` and `$xxxx` (that I usually use)?

Comment: Why is it so common to discourage new learners, at least see reputation of OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple

`$data["xxxx"]` is an element of array and `$xxxx` is normal variable.

You can create array using

```
$data = array();
$data['xxxx'] = 'abc';
$data['yyyy'] = '222';
```

and then output it's element using

```
echo $data['xxxx'];
echo $data['yyyy'];
```

You should definitely look at [Types in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.php)

Comment: as of PHP 5.4 you can write `$data = [];`

Answer (score 0):

`$xxxx` is a simple variable

whereas
`$data["xxxx"]` is a array element where `$data` is name of array and `xxxx` is a key in that array

Answer (score 0):

`$xxxx` is a variable like we have in any languate in which you can store value (string, integer etc):
For example

```
$xxxx = 100;
$xxxx = 'string';
```

But `$data['xxxx']` is an **associative array**. In a simple array you get values on basis of there index position for example

```
$data[0] = "Jona";
$data[1] = "Hex";
echo $data[1];   //will out put 'Hex'
```

But in **associative array** like you mentioned in your question, values at positions are recognized by there name like 'xxxx'. For example:

```
$data['xxxx'] = "This string is saved at xxxx in array $data";
$data['yyyy'] = "This string is saved at yyyy in array $data";
//you can use it like:
echo $data['xxxx'];
```

Like "xxxx" you can give any name to array elements; for more details see [arrays in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: PHP Notice: Array to string conversion Error.

Answer (score 0):

The answer: It depends.

If there was code linking these two variables together, they could potentially be the exact same thing.

```
$data['xxxx'] = &$xxxx;
$xxxx = &$data['xxxx'];
```

Now, there's no difference between these two, setting either variable would be the same thing.

```
<?php

$data = array();

$data['xxxx'] = &$xxxx;
$xxxx = &$data['xxxx'];

$xxxx = 2;
$data['xxxx'] = 4;

echo $xxxx;
echo $data['xxxx'];
```

[Output](https://eval.in/private/557abf7c762ac3): 44

In this case, there is **no difference** between `$data['xxxx']` and `$xxxx`.

If the two variables were not linked, the difference would be, of course, they both have different addresses.

---

In conclusion, I can say however, that `$data["xxxx"]` is an element of `$data`, which is an array.

BUT, I cannot say anything about the `$xxxx`, or the type of values that either variable holds.